# Google Analytics analytics.js setup

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I'm new to Google Analytics and as such just want to make sure I am putting everything in the right places and haven't broken any obvious rules!

I have the analytics code below within the `<head>` tags:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

If I was then to use the following code, could I place it in a separate .js file so I don't have to paste it into every page I need tracking on? And then just link to the .js file of course.

```
var phoneNo = document.getElementById('headerPhone');
addListener(phoneNo, 'click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'phonenumber', 'click', 'header');
});
/**
 * Utility to wrap the different behaviors between W3C-compliant browsers
 * and IE when adding event handlers.
 *
 * @param {Object} element Object on which to attach the event listener.
 * @param {string} type A string representing the event type to listen for
 *     (e.g. load, click, etc.).
 * @param {function()} callback The function that receives the notification.
 */
function addListener(element, type, callback) {
 if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
 else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
```

Also, could I omit the text in the multiline comment?

Then I would just need to put the id on the element, such as:

```
<h3 id="headerPhone" onclick="goog_report_conversion('tel:01000 000000')">01000 000000</h3>
```

The onClick event on the above is for AdWords tracking so ignore that.

To clarify the questions that apparently aren't clear enough:

1) Am I correct in placing the second bit of code in a separate .js file and linking it to all pages?

2) Can I get rid of the multiline comment from the second bit of code?

3) Is the third bit of code correct, in conjunction with the second bit of code, to execute the tracking?(i.e. when the `<h3 id="headerPhone">` is clicked will it cause the second bit of code to execute?).

4) Have I made any errors in the code itself?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: 1) Am I correct in placing the second bit of code in a separate .js file and linking it to all pages? 2) Can I get rid of the multiline comment from the second bit of code? 3) Is the third bit of code correct to fire the tracking?(i.e. the `id` will cause the second bit of code to execute). 4) Have I made any errors in the code itself? I am hoping that as you had to ask, I am doing it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's up to you. You can either set it in external JS file or in the page body/head. As long as definitions will be downloaded before actual use you're safe.
2. Naturally, it's a comment. No need to have it in production.
3. Yes. GA event seems to be correct. As well as calling the function.
4. No.

Comment: Would I be best to link to the external JS file in the `<head>` to make sure they are downloaded before they get used?

Comment: Sure. But just remember that the page will stop rendering until JS file is downloaded.

Comment: I'm getting the following Console Error:

null is not an object (evaluating 'element.addEventListener')
  (anonymous function)

The line of my .js file it refers to is:

`if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);`